# Regular Expression to Extract all Function Declarations

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not good with regular expressions, so I need help with a regular expression that will extract all C function declarations from within a word doc. I've got the word doc loaded in memory and have read the text, so that's not an issue. Also, all functions starts with INTERNAL_ and obviously end with ); e.g.

INTERNAL_DisplayMessage ( param a, int b );

So basically, I need the regular expression that will extract entire function declaration from INTERNAL_ to ;. The return value is same across all APIs, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why didn't it work?

Comment: `MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\(([^)]*)\)");`

This is what I tried, I'm really not good with regular expressions, never had to use those. This regular expression gets me everything in (), I'm trying to figure out how to get INTERNAL_ and ); into this expression.

Comment: please post a question instead of a task request

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: I've been experimenting with several different variations on my own, so don't know how else to put this question.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as `(INTERNAL_.+?\);)` should work. I highly recommend [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for these types of tasks.

Comment: thats not working either...I don't get any matches whatsoever.

Comment: Can you show us the text then, or a small part of it? When I run your code with my regex on the text of your initial post, I get 2 matches.

Comment: Since, it's internal documentation, I can't post it here, but following is the rough format:

`This is method a, that will be called

INTERNAL_MethodA (\n
 int param1,\n
 int param2\n
);\n\n

Note: Call this method carefully.`

Comment: If you go to [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and paste "(INTERNAL_.+?\);)" (without the quotes) into the top box and that text into the bottom box you should get one match. When you hover over it, you should see group 1 is the entire function definition. I get the same thing from C#. If this doesn't work for you it must be something other than the regex that is the problem.

Comment: did you change \n to newline? I just noticed that once I check "dotall" only then I get a match. I tried changing . in regex to [.\n] to compensate for that, but that doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't modify the text at all. However, are you saying the text contains newlines? If so that would require a change in the regex or the matching parameters.

Comment: Yes, the declaration is split among several lines, so I added \n in the sample text. The system won't let me format the text, so that was the only thing I could think of. Btw, I tried using the multi-line option in C#, but that's not helping either.

Comment: Try adding `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` to your `Regex.Matches()` function call.

Comment: still no luck. Is there a way to simulate dotall option in C# or to update regex to account for newline?

Comment: I guess that means it is escaped whitespace which this option doesn't exclude. I don't know if this is kosher but you could use the regex `(INTERNAL_[^]+?\);)`. Instead of using the dot, which excludes whitespace, it uses the negation of an empty character set, i.e. everything.

Comment: Look at my edited answer. You need to specify an option in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this regex:

```
  (INTERNAL_[^ ]+?\s?\(.*?\);)
```

The outer parentheses make all the text of a function to get captured inside a group.

The function declaraton parentheses are escaped with backslash `\(` `\)`, so that they are treated as literals, instead of groupings.

`[^ ]\s?` means any character which is not space, one or more times, follorwed by an optional space just before the opening parenthesis

`.*?` means any character, `*` any number of times (including o), as least as possible

As your functions declarations includes \n inside them, you need to create your regex using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option as the second parameter of the Regex constructor:

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

See doc at: [RegexOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

A good place to chek regexes is this one:

[www.regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/)

it lets you change the language and set options. For the SinleLine option check the 'dot (.) matches every character instead of every character except newlines (Singleline)' option on that page.

Comment: +1 This should give fewer false positives than my answer because it requires the opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: This isn't returning any results at all, not even on the site you mentioned. Please do try it with the newline, I'm still tinkering with parameters - brute force approach basically.

Comment: Yeah, this works for me. This is a better solution that the `[^]` hack I suggested.

Comment: Please, check it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html This uses the .NET regex (there are differences between languages). I've checked it ans I assure you it works fine with the new lines.

Comment: It's matching results, but seems too broad as it's also including parts of documentation E.g in documentation: "INTERNAL_FuncA matches all test. API: INTERNAL_FuncA ( ..);". In these cases entire string is being matched instead of just the declaration.

Comment: `(INTERNAL_[A-Za-z0-9_]+? \(.*?\);)`

Comment: We're making shots in the dark because you didn't show us a text sample. The latest expression I've edited only accepts an optional white space just before the ( of the function. So it matches what you want, unless you give us some extra surprises.

Comment: @Craig W you can use [^ ] to accept all but spaces. Your proposed group is missing some characters, like $, which is valid for function names in most languages.

Comment: `[^ ]` would accept other symbols that are not valid in function names, like `-`, but I suppose there is not much risk of a false positive due to that.